# Windows Firewall - Protected network connections?

Tags: windows, firewall, local-area-network, nic, windows-defender

In Windows Defender Firewall,  under Advanced Settings, there is a "Protected network connections" setting for each profile (Domain, Public, Private). An image of this setting:
[Protected network connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceZWX.png)

My goal is to block all connections on Wireless and let everything go on LAN. First I thought, that this is a great idea, enable the Firewall only for the Wireless Network (leaving Local Area Connection open deliberately), and set the inbound/outbound connections to Block. This way Wireless connection will be blocked, but LAN will not. It did not work: *the outbound connections were blocked on the LAN as well, internet was not working*.

Okay then - I thought - this "Protected network connections" might be then only for rules, not these global settings, so I created a rule to block everything on all profiles, allowed outbound connections on all profiles, removed LAN from protected networks, and thought, now it should work. It is still not working. *Although LAN is not checked in "Protected network connections" (for all profiles to exclude mistakes), internet is still not working due to firewall reasons*.

Then I thought, okay, but then what does this "Protected network connections" do? I did not find any information about it and could not trigger the (lack of) protection. It is possible, that firewall is above the layers of network interface communication, and this has no effect at all? Where to use these settings then? However, when I uncheck the LAN, I also immediately get a notification, that my PC is unprotected.

I also know there is a setting in the rule itself, where you can set on which interface it is active, but it is only the type of interface (LAN, Remote access, Wireless). But that is not good for me, as it might be that I want to enable all on LAN1, and disable all on LAN2, both being wired network interfaces.

('Protect all network connections' group policy setting is not configured.)

Could someone please explain, how this protection works?